# How to generate direct download link for google drive shared link by file id

Tags: javascript, php, google-drive-api, drive

I want to generate google drive direct download link without opening web page.

I have found 1 site which do same thing but I did not find how he is doing.

below is the site which generates direct download link without opening google drive page.

https://links-safety.com/download.php?id=0B475ByfcR9n4a1JMVEZxQno2Tmc

0B475ByfcR9n4a1JMVEZxQno2Tmc is google file and replace with any file.

can anyone tell me how can I do that?I want to make same page like above site.

I tried this url but its not working. instead of starting download it opens page.

https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0BwSYfbOPSw89Rno4LTZpSGF6RUE

Comment: did you tested my answer and link @Jimmy did that worked for you?

Comment: yes its worked for me thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have do something along this lines ..

- go to your Google API console and there create or use existing project ( https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials )
  [image]
- add Google Drive API
- then generate your `key` [image]
- and then you can target URL's with this URL structure: 
  https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/**file_id**?key=**your_key**&alt=media

it is documented on Google API page, here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#downloading_a_file

Comment: Thanks it is working. but above site is using other method. that site generate url like this https://doc-0o-a0-docs.googleusercontent.com  and your method generates https://www.googleapis.com url.

Comment: kresimir pendic can you tell me which php code used this site to generate link ??  https://links-safety.com/download.php?id=0B475ByfcR9n4a1JMVEZxQno2Tmc

Comment: Or a simpler method without API keys, make a POST request. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47625446/661872

Comment: this working but the file name is id of that file