# How to get file name from googleapis direct download

Tags: php, api, curl, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

i want to create direct download link from google drive.

im already ready read this [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625214/generate-custom-direct-download-link-for-google-drive-link/#comment88054178_47625446) but not working if the files already QUOTA_EXCEEDED.

and im already read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45502856/9661872) too. this one is working even if the file already QUOTA_EXCEEDED, but when im download it, the file name is **id of that file** not **name of that file**, i want when i download, it generate **name** not id.

this is example link

https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0B475ByfcR9n4a1JMVEZxQno2Tmc?key=hjags87as6d78asgdahsgd7a6sd&alt=media

ID file = `0B475ByfcR9n4a1JMVEZxQno2Tmc`.

API key = `hjags87as6d78asgdahsgd7a6sd`(this_is_fake_key)

or is there another way to baypass QUOTA_EXCEEDED using script from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625214/generate-custom-direct-download-link-for-google-drive-link/#comment88054178_47625446)?

u can try this link https://links-safety.com/download.php?id=0B475ByfcR9n4a1JMVEZxQno2Tmc. they baypass QUOTA_EXCEEDED.

and im find in some site they using https://video-downloads.googleusercontent.com/ to get direct download link. [this one for example](http://j-raws.me/library/d/down.php?id=NS9IeTdiZUIrSHRIVWVuYXF2aEhaajBBMkFvWVdPcXNxcWdHWlNSOEIxNThGb28rcFJlTUpJUUNTNEhoOS81R2xkZUV2WUdOaCtYTEp3dTVmTlQyL1F4WWFPSHFaTU9veWhmdDRhMXI2WDNMZjRvZk12bVZPS2NyMWd3RU5sekw3RlpzNG4xV05NVVh6aWl4NEp2V1o4UHFBOTl5eXlTUDJML3lEQXBCcmVPNVhlcDlTSTVlYzRzTTJVZlJ4OEg2UmVTODlDUWo4ZDU3SzRhUTJqVU1VZkVoU2Z4UFZyUjV4MWMrUXpLS2JNbz0=)

Comment: Although I'm not sure about the method of download, if the file is shared, when the files is downloaded using the browser, the filename which is used in Google Drive is given. The URL is ``https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=### fileId ###``. If the size of file is large, please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48133080/how-to-download-a-google-drive-url-via-curl-or-wget/48133859#48133859 If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.